# GIS software recommendation

Tags: software-recommendations

I am new to GIS and am currently doing a project related to GIS.

Can somebody recommend me a good GIS software that can:

1. Create custom indoor maps
2. Do custom routes based on custom criteria
3. Generated map can be used for directions on mobile

Comment: I recommend that you separately use each of your three requirements to search here (and elsewhere) for software that people are using to meet them (or similar requirements).  That should enable you to narrow your candidates and ask more focussed questions about any specific requirements that you are concerned each may not be able to meet.

Comment: could you please reopen the question again as I just finished a reply to the question as you closed it.

Comment: OK - but to me it still looks like a question that is too broad for our focussed Q&A format so I view doing this as an exception.

Comment: agree it is too broad. re-closing it would make sense. Just felt it would be a waste not to post the reply.

Comment: Are you wanting to do custom indoor routing?  If so, you may want to refine your question.  I think that will certainly narrow the field of potential candidates.

Answer (score 2):

Try using ArcGIS. It is used for: creating and using maps; compiling geographic data; analyzing mapped information; sharing and discovering geographic information; using maps and geographic information in a range of applications; and managing geographic information in a database.

You can create a map that can be viewed in a browser, desktop or mobile device. Share it on a blog, via email, or embed it in a website.

You can build custom web and mobile applications that incorporate your maps and data.

Links for references:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ArcGIS

https://www.arcgis.com/features/

http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis

https://www.arcgis.com/home/

Answer (score 2):

The big GIS systems is

1. ArcGIS - especially used in industry
2. Mapinfo - especially used in government
3. QGIS - open source and free

*1. Create custom indoor maps:*

Assuming you have some kind of data (gps points or coordinates, floor layout drawings, sketch etc.) this process is called digitizing. If you have a floor layout you can load this into a GIS, rectify it (to give it coordinates) and then draw polygons on top of it to create a new map.

*2. Do custom routes based on custom criteria*

This should be possible in all modern GIS. in QGIS this is done via a plug-in that you download form the plug-in manager.

in 3. you write

> used for directions on mobile

This could mean many things. could you elaborate on this? should be dynamic or static, fit in with some app or accessed by we-blink etc:

Comment: Could you please spell the Esri software correctly? It's also only one GIS platform.  There are other GIS solutions besides ArcGIS and QGIS.